# S3 authentication via EC2 without passing AWS Access Key & Secret key in code or storage

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to access S3 buckets via EC2 machine using python SDK(Boto).
I know we can do by IAM roles by using its access key and secret key. We can use it by hardcoding in code or store it in config file on EC2 local storage.
I know we can create a policy and role and assign to EC2 machine

But is there any another way without putting access key and secret key in python program or ec2 storage we can access S3 bucket or any AWS resources?

My motto is I have to access aws resources via python program without using access key and secret key and secure my access key and secret key.

Comment: You know "we can create a policy and role and assign to EC2 machine" ([read more about retrieving security credentials from instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)). That's about the only way if you don't want to _hardcode_ your secret key or _store_ it on disk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an IAM role and attach the policy AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess - for listing the s3 buckets, for full access attach the AmazonS3FullAccess.

Since you want this operation to be done in ec2, in trust relationship of IAM role, give

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Comment: Thank you for your response Gowtham. I want one more help, Suppose I copied my policy ARN and assigned to two user to use that, at that time how will I know who is using or accessing that application?

Comment: I am not very clear, why do you want to know the user trying to access the application. This question doesn't relate to the original ask. Can you please create a new question? happy to help